# How to get first_value from previous window partition

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I want to display the the BalanceEndOfYesterday Value from the day before in a query as shown below.

```
| Date       | Amout | BalanceEndOfDay | BalanceEndOfYesterday |
|------------|-------|-----------------|-----------------------|
| 2020-04-30 | 10    | 130             | 80                    |
| 2020-04-30 | 20    | 130             | 80                    |
| 2020-04-30 | 30    | 130             | 80                    |
| 2020-04-30 | -10   | 130             | 80                    |
| 2020-04-29 | 50    | 80              | 0                     |
| 2020-04-29 | -10   | 80              | 0                     |
| 2020-04-29 | 40    | 80              | 0                     |
```

My query is

```
SELECT 
    BalanceEndOfDay ,
    first_value(BalanceEndOfDay) OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) -- here is some sort of window needed
FROM AccountTransactions
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` :

```
SELECT at.*, COALESCE(at1.BalanceEndOfDay, 0) AS BalanceEndOfYesterday
FROM AccountTransactions at OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) at1.BalanceEndOfDay
       FROM AccountTransactions at1
       WHERE at1.Date < at.Date
       ORDER BY at1.Date DESC
     ) at1;
```

EDIT : If you want yesterday only balance then you can use `dateadd()` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT at.*, COALESCE(at1.balanceendofday, 0) AS BalanceEndOfYesterday
FROM AccountTransactions at LEFT JOIN
     AccountTransactions at1
     ON at1.date = dateadd(day, -1, at.date);
```

Comment: Based on my interpretation of the question, I would be tempted to use `at1.date = dateadd(day, -1, at.date)` .

Answer (score 1):

We could use `LAG` here, after first aggregating by date to obtain a single end of day balance for each date.  Then, we can join your table to this result to pull in the end of day balance from yesterday.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Date, MAX(BalanceEndOfDay) AS BalanceEndOfDay,
        LAG(MAX(BalanceEndOfDay), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Date) As BalanceEndOfYesterday
    FROM AccountTransactions
    GROUP BY Date
)

SELECT
    a1.Date,
    a1.Amount,
    a1.BalanceEndOfDay,
    a2.BalanceEndOfYesterday
FROM AccountTransactions a1
INNER JOIN cte a2
    ON a1.Date = a2.Date
ORDER BY
    a1.Date DESC;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using only window functions, you can use:

```
select at.*,
       max(case when prev_date = dateadd(day, -1, date) then prev_BalanceEndOfDay end) over (partition by date) as prev_BalanceEndOfDay
from (select at.*,
             lag(BalanceEndOfDay) over (order by date) as prev_BalanceEndOfDay,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date
      from accounttransactions at
     ) at;
```

Note:  This interprets "the day before" as being exactly one day before.  It is means "the day before in the data", then the first comparison should just be `max(case when prev_date <> date . . . )`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=937e802c52c39980cdedcb0881b5be56) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that in databases that fully support the `range` window specification, this can be done directly with logic like this:

```
max(BalanceEndOfDay) over (order by datediff(day, '2000-01-01', date)
                           range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                          )
```

Alas, SQL Server does not support this (standard) functionality.